# Split html source into multiple files

Tags: html

Does HTML support splitting source over multiple files? I'm looking for some equivalent of C++'s `#include`; or maybe something like C#'s `partial`; an element that could take source path and inject the file contents at that place.

Apologies if this has been asked before. Google and SO searches didn't return much. I'm not a web guy, but the only solution I found was using an `iframe`, which many people do not like for various reasons.

It is just that my html source is becoming huge and I want to manage it by splitting into multiple files.

Comment: not sure if that's what you are asking for, but have a look up this. https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_html_include.asp

Comment: Unfortunately this isn't part of the HTML spec, but there are many server-side and client-side tools which give you this ability.

Comment: @marmeladze: Seems interesting, although it is a custom solution as far as I understand.

Comment: [`w3-include`](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_html_include.asp) is quite useful, although it may not work if you are not running on a server

Comment: @CarlJan: Yep. Thinking about how large webpages can/do get, it would be all but necessary to have language-level support for includes. Seems to be a big omission in my opinion now that the language is 30-so years old.

Comment: yes, it is a custom solution and might not work in every occasion, but that's html - a markup language, rather than a fully fledged programming language.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is easily possible, if you are running PHP:

The PHP Language has the "include" command built in.
Therefore you can have your "index.php" (note you have to change the suffix, for the PHP parser to kick-in) and simply use following syntax.

```
<html>
  <head>
    [...] (header content you want to set or use)
  </head>
  <body>
    <?php
      include "relative/path/to/your/firstfile.html";
      include "relative/path/to/your/secondfile.html";
      include "relative/path/to/your/evenwithothersuffix/thirdfile.php";
      include "relative/path/to/your/fourth/file/in/another/folder.html";
    ?>
    [...] (other source code you whish to use in the HTML body part)
  </body>
</html>
```

Basically making you main index.php file a container-file and the included html files the components, which you like to maintain seperately.

For further reading I recommend the [PHP Manual](http://php.net/manual/de/function.include.php) and the [W3Schools Include](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_includes.asp) Page.

Comment: Thanks. This would work nicely in my current situation, but not in HTML-only environments. I'll mark this as answer if we don't get anything better.

Comment: Giving -1 since the question was asking specifically about vanilla HTML

Comment: Literally what PHP was designed for. Good ol' PHP. From the Good ol' days.

Answer (score 6):

You can't, at least not in flat-HTML. What you can do is using Javascript to load and place the snippets.  `iframe`s are also non-ideal because contrary to what happens with directives like `#include` and `partial`, those snippets will never be compiled in one single page.

However, I think it's important here to understand how your pages will be served.  Is this a static website?  Because in this case I would write a simple script in your language of choice to compile the page.  Let's say that you have a base like this:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <!-- ... -->
    </head>

    <body>
        {{ parts/navigation.html }}
        <!-- ... -->
    </body>
</html>
```

You could write a script that runs through this file line by line and loads the content into a variable named, for example, `compiled_html`.  When it finds `{{ file }}` it opens `file`, reads its content and append it to `compiled_html`.  When it gets to the end, it writes the content of the variable into a HTML file.  How you would implement it depends on the languages you know.  I'm sure that it's pretty straightforward to do it in C#.

This way you'll be able to split the source of your HTML pages into multiple files (and reuse some parts if you need them), but you'll still end up with fully functional single files.

Comment: This, just like Julian's answer requires code and would not work in HTML-only situations.

Comment: They're two very different approaches to the same problem. Since you're asking to split a static HTML page into multiple files, I imagine you don't need to change the page on the fly. Using PHP or another server-side language to just include some files would be an overkill since the PHP interpreter would be called everytime the page gets requested. If you need to modify the page on the fly there are better approaches.

However, what I'm suggesting is not a server side solution. You would compile your files once, upload your static files, and live happy ever after.

Comment: Ah, I just re-read your answer. I don't think that is a workable solution. In static HTML situations, especially during designing, no one would want to pass these files through a custom utility after every edit, just to see how it looks. Not only it is tedious, it will kill design-time support in any HTML designer. If this were really the last option, @marmeladze's suggestion of using `w3-data` is far more manageable.

Answer (score 1):

not possible with static html.

in general, this problem (lazy-fetching of content) is solved with a template processor.

two options:

1. template processor runs on the server side

   - any language
   - static website generators, server side rendering
2. template processor runs on the client side

   - javascript
   - web frameworks

Comment: Well, at this point it's **far easier to rely on PHP doing it completely automatic**, with the `include()` function; **one single line of programming/code**. As the "best" answer, from 2017, already explained; although none of the answers solves the question properly (it was asking for a HTML-way).